# Showing that $\{x\in\mathbb R^n: \|x\|=\pi\}\cup\{0\}$ is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I do have problems with connected sets so I got the following exercise:

> $X:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|=\pi\}\cup\{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Why is $X$ not connected?

My attempt: I have to find disjoint open sets $U,V\ne\emptyset$ such that $U\cup V=X$ .

Let $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|=\pi\}$ and $V=\{0\}$. Then $V$ is relative open since $$V=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|<1\}\cap X$$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|<1\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this right? and why is $U$ open?

Comment: $U$ is open because $U=\{x\in\mathbb R^n;\ ||x||>0\}\cap X$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263008/consider-a-and-b-of-mathbbr2-a-x-x-sin-frac1xx-in0-1-and).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yup, that's right! And similarly, you can see that $U$ is open because $U=W\cap X$ where $$W=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\tfrac{\pi}{2}<\|x\|<\tfrac{3\pi}{2}\}$$
is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. One way of seeing that $W$ is open is noting that the function $\|\cdot\|:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $W$ is the preimage of the open set $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$.

Comment: I have a stupid question: this relies on $X$ being open, right?

Comment: @Lucas: Sorry, I should have been clearer: $U$ is *relatively open in* $X$, but $U$ is **not** open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is relatively open $X$, by definition, because it is the intersection of an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (namely $W$) with $X$.

Comment: OK, I'm still a little confused (my problem entirely). Is the general idea with these problems to say that there is an set that is a superset of the set you are testing, and that set *is* open, so as long as your can say these supersets are disconnected, you can say the originals are?

Comment: @Lucas: It may help you to look at the Wikipedia page on the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). Remember, "open" is *not* an inherent property of a set, it depends on the ambient space we're working in (which will often be left implicit). Properly speaking, we need a set $Y$ and a topology $T$ on $Y$; only then we can make sense of the statement "*$Z$ is an open subset of $Y$*". So, when I say "*$U$ is open*", what I mean is "$U$ is an open subset of $X$, where $X$ has been given the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^n$".

Comment: To demonstrate that the set $X$ in this problem is disconnected, we need to demonstrate the existence of two disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$. Again, "*open subset of $X$*" here means "*subset of $X$ that is open in the subspace topology $X$ gets from $\mathbb{R}^n$*".

Comment: This will help me: is $X$ relatively open in $X$?

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, that's true. If $Y$ is our beginning topological space, then $Y$ is open as a subset of $Y$ [by the definition of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Open_sets_definition). Therefore, for any given subset $X\subseteq Y$ whatsoever, $X$ is the intersection of an open set of $Y$ with $X$: namely, $X=X\cap Y$.

Comment: Sweet, cool, I get it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is right. And $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\|x\|>0\}\cap X$.

Answer (score 4):

A more fancy approach: it will suffice to say that the singleton $\{0\}$ is a clopen (=closed and open) set. It is closed, because one point sets are always closed. It is open, because it is $X \cap \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ || x || < 1 \}$

Answer (score 4):

Alternative: the norm $\|\cdot \|$ is 1-Lipschitz by the triangular inequality, whence continuous. The image of your set under this continuous map is $\{0\}\cup\{\pi\}$, which is disconnected. So your set can't be connected, since the continuous image of a connected space is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Any open set O in $\mathbb R^n$ intersected with $X$ yields an open set $O\cap X$ in X.

Proof: by definition, a set $S\subseteq X$ is open in $X$,  iff for each $x \in S$ an $\epsilon>0$ exists such that the ball $B(x,X,\epsilon)= \{ y \in X : ||x-y||< \epsilon\} \subseteq S$. Now if $S=O\cap X$ for an open set $O \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, then for each $x \in S$, there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $B(x,\mathbb R^n,\epsilon) \subseteq O$. This implies that $B(x,X,\epsilon)=B(x,\mathbb R^n,\epsilon)\cap X \subseteq O\cap X=S$.

So $V$ is open. Similarly, $U= \{x\in \mathbb R^n: 3<||x||<4\}\cap X$ is also open in $X$. 
As $X$ is the disjoint union of two open sets, it is not connected.